# Is there an acknowledgements environment for the article document class?

Tags: sectioning, abstract, acknowledgements

I am trying to add a section for acknowledgements in my document that behaves the same way as

```
\begin{abstract} 
....
\end{abstract}
```

Is there a command for this or do you have to create an environment and if so how do I do this?
I'm new to `LaTeX` so apologies if it's a silly question.

Comment: Welcome. As far as I know, there is no such environment. But you can somehow "create" your own. I added it to the `toc` using `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements} \input{acknowledgements} \newpage` from an extern `.tex` file to my main file. What  are the requirements for your section?

Comment: While abstracts are often set with different margins, font shapes and maybe even sizes, acknowledgments are typically set as an unnumbered section in the primary document style.  Thus, `\section*{Acknowledgments}`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work with the default document classes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}% Rename Abstract to Acknowledgements
  \begin{abstract}
}{%
  \end{abstract}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]
\end{acknowledgements}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to get an abstract-like acknowledgement environment.

1. Do as @Werner suggested.
2. Provide complete code for the environment
3. Change the `\abstractname` and use `abstract`.

The last two are shown below.

```
% artackprob.tex  SE 591728
\documentclass%[twocolumn]
%  [titlepage]
  {article}
%%%% an abstract-like acknowledgement environment
\newcommand{\ackname}{Acknowledgements}
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{acknowledgement}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
      \bfseries \ackname
      \@endparpenalty\@M
    \end{center}}%
  {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{acknowledgement}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \section*{\ackname}%
    \else
      \small
      \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \ackname\vspace{-0.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
      \end{center}%
      \quotation
    \fi}
    {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Ack and Abs}
\author{Peter W.}
\maketitle

\begin{acknowledgement}
A bow to my helpers.

A plague to some others.
\end{acknowledgement}

\begin{abstract}
All thought is an abstraction.

Actions count.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
Changed the abstract name to Acknowledgements.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I think it probably better, as commentators have suggested, to just use a `\section*`.